# Error message "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Customer.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;D)V "

Tags: java, class, object

I keep getting the same error message when running this program. This is what i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Customer.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;D)V 
at Customer5.input(Customer5.java:35)<b>---(See below (code) to refer to lines 35 & 7)
at Customer5.main(Customer5.java:7)
```

Another thing is that the class "Customer" shows a message that says "The type Customer is already defined."

```
import java.util.*;
public class Customer5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Customer[] customers=input();//This is line 7
        customers=sort(customers);
        output(customers);
    }


    public static Customer[] input(){

        Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;


        String name;
        double debt;


        System.out.print("Enter number of customers :");
        n=input.nextInt();

        Customer[] customers=new Customer[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){

            System.out.print("Enter name:");
            name=input.next();

            System.out.print("Enter debt:");
            debt=input.nextDouble();

            customers[i]=new Customer(name, debt);//This is line 35
        }
        return customers;
    }


    public static Customer[] sort(Customer[] customers){

        Customer temp;
        for(int i=0; i<customers.length; i++){

             for(int j=i+1; j<customers.length; j++){

                   if(customers[j-1].debt>customers[j].debt){

                         temp=customers[j-1];
                         customers[j-1]=customers[j];
                         customers[j]=temp;
                   }
             }
        }
              return customers;
    }



     public static void output(Customer[] customers){
            for(int i=0; i<customers.length; i++){
             System.out.println(customers[i].name+"\t" +customers[i].debt);
            }
     }



} 

class Customer{ //this line shows a message that says:The type Customer is already defined

    public String name;
    public Double debt;

    public Customer(String name, double debt){
       this.name=name;
       this.debt=debt;
    }

}
```

I don't know what to do in order to fix it. I am not very familiar with this type of error message. I'd really appreciate any feedback or comments on how to approach this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Recompile your class and all related classes.

Comment: An IDE will handle all of this for you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tested, it works fine for me.

Find "clear and build" option in your IDE, it should do the trick.

---

Also make sure, that in your project does not exist other Customer class.

Comment: The problem was that I had another Customer class. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 4):

This Class runs fine for me, issue is there must be some other Customer class in your package or application which doesnt have constructor `public Customer(String name, double debt)` .

Try clicking Ctrl + Shift + R and search Customer or 
Press Ctrl + H, search Customer in all java files

Comment: Maybe it will help others: it is also good to know that upgrading from an older library may cause such exceptions if you do not make sure that the new lib is also available on the running server too. Such a situation may occur when you use maven and have the lib declared as <scope>provided</scope> - this means that you must assure that the lib is available at the runtime.